# Tooltips cutoff in container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap tooltips, and they are currently being cut off on my page.  I removed overflow-x properties to try to ensure that the tooltip is visible, but they are still being cut off:

[image]

I've looked up some possible solutions, but I can't set the position of the tooltips to fixed or change the parent of the tooltips because they need to scroll with the elements in my container:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qoNkpFAHr0o&feature=youtu.be

Here is how I add the tooltips:

```
$('#step_name').tooltip(
{
    title: "1. Add step title",
    placement: "left",
    container: ".editDetailView",
    trigger: "manual",
    position: "absolute"
});
$('#uploadMedia').tooltip(
{
    title: "2. Upload images/videos",
    placement: "left",
    container: ".editDetailView",
    trigger: "manual",
    position: "absolute"
});
$('.detailViewText').tooltip(
{
    title: "3. Add step description",
    placement: "left",
    container: ".editDetailView",
    trigger: "manual",
    position: "absolute"
});
$('.update_step_button').tooltip(
{
    title: "4. Click to create step",
    placement: "bottom",
    container: ".editDetailView",
    trigger: "manual",
    position: "absolute"
});
```

Here is the CSS on the container elements:

```
.processBlog{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    form{
        overflow: auto;
        .stepDetailView{
           overflow-y: auto;
           .editDetailView{
               position: relative;
               overflow-y: hidden;
             }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you send a link to the page where this problem occurs or at least create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @scientiffic is this issue fixed? If yes please consider accepting one solution as accepted answer....

Answer (score 11):

This can be fixed either with JS or via `data-container` attribute

**JS method**

```
$(element).tooltip({
         title: "Some text",
         container: "body"
});
```

**Using `data-container` example**

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" 
            data-placement="top"
            data-container="body" 
            title="I am a tooltip">Tooltip</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! Never knew about the data-container method!

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the container option for the tooltip:

```
$(element).tooltip({
         title: "Title",
         container: "#calendar"
});
```

Note: You'd want to use a container that is above the container cutting off the image.

See the options here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-options

Before/After Photo

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably your problem: `position: "absolute"`

Why not use `data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom"`

```
<input type="text" name="text" data-toggle="tooltip" data placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">
```

And initialize it with

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks - when I removed the absolute placement and added the data elements (changing data placement to left), the tooltips were still cut off

Comment: My guess: you're applying CSS that is interfering with Bootstrap's CSS. Regardless, putting tooltips on the top or bottom should prevent them from being cut off.

Comment: I'd like them all to be on the left so it looks more consistent, even if adding it to the bottom or top ensures that they're visible.

Comment: Then you're going to need to shift your content to the right to make room for the tooltips. You can't have tooltips to the left of something that fills the viewport and expect them to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the tooltip direction to the right? 
Here is an example for a button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
```

More information [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

Comment: thanks for your response - I'd like the tooltips to be on the left, though.

Comment: @scientiffic this is not something you can do, because you are on the limit of the window, so there are  ways:
1. Add enough **margin-left** the the titlles with tooltip
2. Make a script that move the title to the right to make enough space to the tooltip to display