# Tooltip flickering on show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

On my webpage, I want tooltips to appear when the user loads the page, but then I want them to disappear after the user scrolls in a container.  If they scroll back to the top of the container, the tooltips should reappear.  This is because I couldn't find a way to solve another problem [[Tooltips cutoff in container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287914/tooltips-cutoff-in-container])

I thought the code should be quite straightforward - I check the scrollTop of the container and determine whether or not to show the tooltips:

```
$('.stepDetailView').scroll(function(e){
    console.log($(this).scrollTop());
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 0){
        $('#step_name').tooltip('hide');
        $('#uploadMedia').tooltip('hide');
        $('.detailViewText').tooltip('hide');
        $('.update_step_button').tooltip('hide');
    }else{
        $('#step_name').tooltip('show');
        $('#uploadMedia').tooltip('show');
        $('.detailViewText').tooltip('show');
        $('.update_step_button').tooltip('show');
    }
});
```

This seems to work for fading out the tooltips, but when I want the tooltips to reappear, they seem to flicker for a second before fading out:

http://youtu.be/4WtiAoPrK1o

How can I ensure the tooltips stay visible?

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have solved the problem by using a timeout:

```
// hide or show tooltips depending on scroll position
$('.stepDetailView').scroll(function(e){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if($('.stepDetailView').scrollTop() > 0){
            $('#step_name').tooltip('hide');
            $('#uploadMedia').tooltip('hide');
            $('.detailViewText').tooltip('hide');
            $('.update_step_button').tooltip('hide');
        }else{
            $('#step_name').tooltip('show');
            $('#uploadMedia').tooltip('show');
            $('.detailViewText').tooltip('show');
            $('.update_step_button').tooltip('show');

        }
    }, 50);
});
```